# How to create dynamic TreeView for local c: drive in mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Please help me to solve this problem 
I'm working on an ERP system.The problem is how to create a dynamic TreeView in mvc, which can retrieve files only from local C: drive & upload these files on remote server abc(abc is the name of the server).

The example of TreeView is given below in picture

[image]

Comment: web sites cannot access the browser's local drives without some sort of custom control that has elevated permissions. Why not just use the built-in file upload control?

Comment: It would be a huge security issue to allow browsers by default to see an end-users files/locations.  You can't even programmatically set a file-input form field.

Comment: @DStanley your file control upload point  is right but in my case i have required treeview